# What is the shiur for anointing on Yom Kippur?

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, shiurim-measurements, oil, inuy-affliction

Is there a minimum shiur to be [chayav](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1352) (liable) for anointing on Yom Kippur, and, if so, what is it? The gemarah ([Yoma 76b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=76b&format=pdf)) seems to learn it out as a comparison to food consumption: would that mean it has the same shiurim?

Comment: Just to clarify, by _m'chayav_ you mean obligated in Karet, not just Makkat Mardut or and issur aseh or something.

Comment: @DoubleAA - One cannot incur *kareis* for anointing on Yom Kippur, only for eating or drinking (or forbidden labor).

Comment: Actually, @Fred, I think Melachah is also not liable for Kareith.  I could be mistaken, though.

Comment: @SethJ http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%94

Comment: Oh, that's right. I was thinking no death penalty. Yes, there is an Isur Kareith for Melachah. My bad. thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The *Mazal Sha'ah* on the Rambam infers that the *shi'ur l'chayyev* for anointing with *t'rumah* oil is a *k'zayis*, based on R' Yehudah's opinion in the gemara (*K'risus* 6b) who holds that a person is liable for a *k'zayis* of prohibited anointing with the *shemen hamishchah* ([Commentary to *Mishneh Torah*, *Hil. T'rumos* 10:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=33900&rid=6628)). (One should note that it is still Biblically forbidden to anoint with even less than a *k'zayis*, at least in the case of the *shemen hamishchah*).

Although in those cases the oil itself is a prohibited substance, one might consider further extrapolating the above standard to the prohibition against anointing on Yom Kippur. However, disagreement among the Rishonim about the Biblical or rabbinic status of the anointing prohibition on Yom Kippur suggests that there must at least be no Biblical penalty for anointing. Rashi and the Rambam both maintain that the punishment for violation is *makas mardus* (*Rashi* on the *Rif*, *Shabbos*, Chapter 9; Rambam's *Peirush HaMishnayos*, *Shabbos* 9:4, and *Tosafos Yom Tov*, ibid., who clarifies the Rambam's position). The lack of a Biblical penalty is confirmed by the *Yerushalmi* (*Yoma* 8:1; see also *Korban HaEidah* ibid., s.v. *Aval lo l'onesh*)  Therefore, the issue of a liable quantity seems moot.

Furthermore, a lengthy halachic discussion by Dayan Y.Y. Fisher ([*Even Yisrael*, *Hil. Ma'achalos Asuros* 17:27](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=146&rid=4971)) yields the conclusion that, according to those Rishonim who view anointing as Biblically forbidden, the Biblical prohibition against consuming a *chatzi shiur* of nourishment on Yom Kippur may be derived from the prohibition against anointing (which is itself derived from *Daniel*, 10:3,12). This seems to be premised on the lack of a minimum *shi'ur* for anointing on Yom Kippur.

Notably, the *Semag* distinguishes between Biblically and rabbinically prohibited anointing, though not in terms of the quantity of ointment used. He maintains that a criterion for the Biblical prohibition against anointing on Yom Kippur is anointing the entire body, while anointing even part of the body is forbidden rabbinically (*Tosafos Y'shanim*, *Yoma* 77b). This view is echoed by the *Mabit* (*Kiryas Sefer*, *Hil. Sh'visas Asor*, 3).

See [here](http://ybm.org.il/hebrew/LessonArticle.aspx?item=1303) and [here](http://rygb.blogspot.com/2005/07/daf-halachah-shabbos-86a-partial.html) for further halachic discussion on this topic.

Comment: do you perhaps mean revi'is and not kezayis?

Comment: @vram - *K'zayis* is the measure used by the gemara, even though oil is liquid. I've seen this elsewhere in the Talmud, as well. I assume that this literally means the equivalent volume of a solid *k'zaiyis*, but you are welcome to research this.

Comment: @vram Kezayis shows up as a liquid measurement also by eating blood and the after bracha on wine (accd to some rishonim) IIRC.

Comment: @vram is correct, since here oil is forbidden by comparison to drinking, and based on its quality to provide nourishment. Hence it should be reviis

Comment: @PM It is, in fact, k'zayis. Are you arguing that the gemara actually meant "revi'is" (which is *not* a corresponding volume), or are you arguing "it is, but hadn't ought to be"?

Comment: @Fred I'm not addressing the gemarah in krisus, but rather the one in Yoma

Comment: Anyone notice that oil (for purposes of the Gemara) comes from olives? As for @DoubleAA's comment about blood, that could be relating to the fact that it may have a Din of meat (I don't recall where this is discussed, nor the conclusion, only that it is mentioned and commented on).  As for the wine, well, at least I can say it doesn't come up until the Rishonim, right?

Comment: @PM You bring up an interesting point, but *sichah kishsiyah* vis-a-vis Yom Kippur is not a full-fledged comparison, and the Vilna Gaon, in fact, states that the comparison is brought as a *zecher* specifically to discount the possibility that other comparisons may be drawn for other facets of halachah (*Sh'nos Eliyahu*, *Shabbos* 9:4).

Comment: To correct my previous comment, the Vilna Gaon does in fact seem to extend the *zecher* of *sicha kishsiya* to other prohibitions (*Bei'ur HaGR"A* OC 326:10, s.v. "או בשאר חלב"), though the *Sh'nos Eliyahu* source mentions that *sicha kishsiya* is a mere *zecher* and that *sicha* on Yom Kippur is not subject to *kareis*. I'm not sure how far the *sicha kishsiya* comparison can extend in general.