# Why is there no asher yatzar after marital relations?

Tags: blessing, asher-yatzar

[No Blessing on marital relations?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36242/no-blessing-on-sexual-intercourse) discusses a before blessing.

Why is there no after blessing for ejaculation?

Here are some reasons why ejaculation is different from sneezing

1. It occurs in the "nether regions", like the other asher yatzar activities
2. It involves substance moving from deep within the body to outside the body whereas the substance of a sneeze is not very deep within the body.

Comment: Would you be at a health risk if that faculty were blocked?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=722&st=&pgnum=68

Comment: Yes! If your ureter is blocked during ejaculation, your semen will backfire into your bladder. I can't find info on whether this is unhealthy, but if it happens every time, one won't be able to have children.

Comment: not having children wouldn't constitute אי אפשר להתקיים

Comment: But not being able to pass gass would be a אי אפשר להתקיים yet no asher yatzar is said on that

Answer (score 1):

Asher Yatzar says "that if one of them were opened or one of them were closed, a person would be unable to maintain himself" i.e. the functions that we say Asher Yatzar on pose health problems would we not be able to perform them.  Many people get vasectomies and are fine.  So the blessing isn't appropriate.

Comment: People survive colostomies too.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure why providing an alternate route for waste proves anything? That faculty is not ended, just rerouted.

Comment: Vasectomies don't stop semen production TTBOMK; it just gets rerouted.

Comment: @DoubleAA see [here](http://www.webmd.com/sex/birth-control/vasectomy-14387) it is reabsorbed, not emitted.  As opposed to waste, which has an alternate route to emission.

Comment: Define emitted. It leaves the regular שבילי הזרע.

Comment: @DoubleAA but it remains in your body.  Waste does not.  Waste remaining in your body is harmful.  Semen is not.

Comment: What I had in mind when I asked the question is that the danger occurs when the semen has already been produced and  now "wants" to come out, but it cannot due to a blockage.

Comment: @ClintEastwood After a vasectomy semen is still produced.  See linked article in comment above.

Comment: I think you need to prove that if the organ is blocked it is not harmful. The Berachah is about the body working properly, not about waste finding its way out of the body.

Comment: @SethJ a vasectomy is the organ being blocked.  I'm not sure what else to say.

Comment: Semen still exits.

Comment: @SethJ right... and yet people survive.  Yaakov survived for 60 years with semen production and no expulsion.  The existence of semen isn't harmful.  That's my whole point.

Comment: Right. And my point is that that's an inadequate proof. You need to prove that total organ blockage is not harmful. At least, IMO.

Comment: @SethJ maybe I don't understand what you mean by total organ blockage.  In a vasectomy, the organ is totally blocked.  And not harmful.  So can you clarify for me?

Comment: Does Halachah regard the vas as an organ?

Comment: [Clint's comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36253/why-is-there-no-asher-yatzar-after-sex/36254?noredirect=1#comment94404_36253) about passing gas seems like a good counter-example to his own question.