# Why can I not say a b'racha before taking a regular bath at home?

Tags: blessing, showering-bathing

Why can I not say a b'racha before taking a regular bath at home? I understand, in such a case, a person might be "immodest" and the bathroom is, well, a bathroom. But still, I do feel a similar sense of gratitude for Hashem's creative gifts when I say a b'racha over an apple as I do when I stop and think (especially when I have had a really upsetting day and I'm feeling disconnected from my prayers) "Well, I can certainly be grateful; here I am with clean water and Hashem allows me to partake of it."

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://mi.yodeya.com/q/34155.

Comment: this answer addresses your question, I think! http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33360/is-there-a-blessing-on-anointing/33362#33362