# Blessings for a new home

Tags: halacha, blessing, home-house

I recently bought a new house. I was wondering if there is a special blessing and other acts one can make for the new house? Maybe a special tehillim to read?

(I've already installed the mezuzah, got my torah books, initiated torah readings and made a special tzedakah).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bracha over Shelter](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48762/bracha-over-shelter)

Comment: IIRC, there is a small black book that I think is called "Guide for the Gabbai", or something similar. My shul uses it, frequently, esp. when we have to *Mi Shebrach* for baby namings, Bar Mitzvha, aufruf, etc. I think they include a blessing for someone who purchased a new home. I'll see if I can locate it during Shabbat.

Comment: @Shokhet, the earlier question is about a daily blessing thanking God for putting a roof over people's heads (irrespective of whether the person making the blessing has such a roof). The current question is about what to do on buying a house. I don't see that it's a duplicate at all.

Comment: I seem to recall seeing a Sephardic prayer book (perhaps called _Shaare Tzion_? but my mind may be deceiving me) with a bunch of prayers recited on moving in to a new home. Don't know whether purchase was a criterion, though.

Answer (score 2):

The Mishna ([Brachot 9:3](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.9.2-3)) lists building a new house right alongside buying new clothes, and thus (as ruled in [ShA OC 223:3-5](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayyim.223.3)), if the house is just for you you should recite a Shehechiyanu blessing, and if the house is shared with others you'd recite HaTov VeHaMeitiv, just as you would with new clothes. (Of course you should CYLOR to verify how this Halacha applies in your specific case.)

Additionally you should look into the custom of having a [Chanukat HaBayit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18001/759) -- a Home Dedication.

Comment: i also thought so but then the word "building" scared me, that maybe only building and not buying, (i understand that anything that is good you can say Shehechiyanu anyway). why only by clothing do they say about sharing, and not by a house, arent most houses shared (but it says to say Shehechiyanu).

Comment: @hazoriz I've never heard anyone distinguish between buying and building, and so it is ruled here http://www.thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol4Issue3.pdf. (Possibly the Mishna is playing with the pasuk בנה בית ולא חנכו.) Some houses are shared, some aren't. Just depends on the situation.