# Should one say "Shehechiyanu" after renovating part of his home?

Tags: blessing, shehecheyanu

My rav told me it is appropriate to say "Shehechiyanu" after one purchases a home because this gives him joy. Would the bracha be appropriate if you are joyed because you are getting a new bathroom or kitchen, and, perhaps b/c as a result, it improved your home value?

**Premise**: There is some guideline as to the type of "joy" that warrants saying Shehchiyanu. I don't quite understand what's within those guidelines and what isn't. For example, one says Shehechiyanu when wearing new clothes. But I don't know of anyone saying Shehechiyanu upon getting their 1st job or 1st paycheck. IMO, getting your first job / paycheck is more joyous than wearing a new suit.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61861/759